# how to add an attribute to a light using python

Tags: python

I'm new in python and I'm trying to add an attribute to a maya light shape. The script should works like that: for each light.shape I've selected add a 'mtoa_constant_lightGroup' attribute:

```
import maya.cmds as pm

lightSelect= pm.ls (sl=True, dag=True, leaf=True)

for elem in lightSelect:
    pm.addAttr (elem, ln='mtoa_constant_lightGroup', at=long, dv=0)
    pm.setAttr (e=True, keyable=True, elem +'.mtoa_constant_lightGroup')
```

But when I run the script I've got this error:

```
Error: line 1: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: It's a typo. You want `dv=0`, not `dv-0`.

Comment: yes sorry it was a write mistake, anyway even with d=0 I got the same error

Comment: The second errror is that you cannot use a positional argument after the keyword arguments in the last line. I know I am just restating the error message, but I don't know what you don't understand about it.

Comment: Try moving the keyword arguments to the end, e.g. `pm.setAttr(elem +'.mtoa_constant_lightGroup', e=True, keyable=True)`

Comment: thank martin, if I try yuor suggestion, I've got another error: # Error: line 1: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 6: Type specified for new attribute is unknown. #

Answer (score 1):

In the following line from your code you have a positional argument after a keyword argument, which does not make sense.

```
pm.setAttr (e=True, keyable=True, elem +'.mtoa_constant_lightGroup')
# ---- here ----------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

fix it!
so as Martin said I had to move the keyword arguments to the end 
then for the error " # Error: line 1: RuntimeError: file  line 6: Type specified for new attribute is unknown." I needed to set `at=long` as a string, e.g.

```
`pm.addAttr (elem, ln='mtoa_constant_lightGroup', at="long", dv=0)`
```

The final scripts is this:

```
import maya.cmds as pm

lightSelect= pm.ls (sl=True, dag=True, leaf=True)

for elem in lightSelect:
    pm.addAttr (elem, ln='mtoa_constant_lightGroup', at="long", dv=0)
    pm.setAttr(elem +'.mtoa_constant_lightGroup', e=True, keyable=True)
```

thanks for all your helps